# How do I adjust the size of a path point along one axis?

Tags: bezier-curves, transforms

If you have a path curve bevel, you can adjust the size with alt + s. How can I adjust the size, but only along one axis?

Comment: You cannot.  You can, instead, create a bevel object that is different in one axis than another, use that for the curve, and adjust the tilt of the curve as necessary to define how that bevel object cross-section is rotated around the curve.